"GrammyError in middleware" error: 404 on edit, supposedly because no edit was made. Code straight out of Telegram bot API docs
I'm trying to make a in-chat interactive menu on telegram, and the first thing was ofc looking at the docs. I'm running this code (which is linked in the very first page of the bot api docs, and does not accept submissions for issues); Every time I click the "Next" button, it hangs out and the console logs: GrammyError in middleware: Call to 'editMessageText' failed! (400: Bad Request: message is not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the message)
Changing the sourced menu for the /menu command, and providing the secondMenu +secondMenuMarkup, it is possible to click back, and the msg is edited in place to the "firstMenu".

Changing this line:
const firstMenuMarkup = new InlineKeyboard().text(nextButton, backButton);

to this:
const firstMenuMarkup = new InlineKeyboard().text(nextButton, nextButton);

resolves the issue.
